# Limpar tela prompt MySQL

Tags: mysql

Alguém sabe como limpar a tela do prompt do `MySQL`?

Depois de um certo tempo a tela fica cheia e quero limpar. Faço isso no prompt do Windows, mas do MySQL não consegui.

Já tentei:

> `\! cls`, `CLS`, `cls`

Obrigado!

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesta pergunta (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807836/how-to-clear-mysql-screen-console-in-windows), parece que há um bug que não permite a execução desta operação no windows.

Comment: @ldeoliveira obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível realizar esse procedimento no Windows.

Veja nesse [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=58680), o bug foi encontrado em 2010 e ainda não tem um comando similar para o Windows.

Comment: obrigado, por enquanto parece não ter jeito mesmo. Blz.

Comment: Precisando estamos ai..

Comment: Só não se esquece de escolher uma resposta correta para a sua pergunta.

Answer (score -3):

`system cls;`(windows) ou `system clear;`(linux)